# Is it only writting to a HDD which causes failure?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

This is probably a dumb question, but for platter drives specifically, is it only writing to them which causes eventual failure?

Like, if you wrote a load of data once, and then only ever read it after that, would you expect sector failures?

I get it can mechanically fail at some point, so I'm just thinking from a platter having bad sectors.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it only wittting to a HDD which causes failure](https://superuser.com/questions/1646089/is-it-only-wittting-to-a-hdd-which-causes-failure)

Comment: Please take the time to read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions)